# NGINX extensionless PHP file is being downloaded (with authentication)

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

**Explanation:**

I'm trying to configure my NGINX project as an extensionless (PHP) project. It seems to work fine, except when I will be using basic authentication with an exception for a specific folder.

My project has an API folder which requires the extensionless settings. I'm retrieving my API files in a PHP `file_get_contents` function (it's a very basic API and meant for local use only). The project has a basic authentication, but (because of `file_get_contents`) I want to create an exception for the API folder. Therefore I have added the following lines to the API folder location:

```
location ~ ^/api/ {    
   auth_basic "off";
   allow 127.0.0.1;
   allow ::1;
   deny all;
}
```

However, due to this location, the files are being downloaded in that folder instead of executed. If I remove this location, the file will be executed fine (except for the `file_get_contents` function, which returns a 401.

**Problem**

`file_get_contents` returns a 401 because of the authentication. `file_get_contents` should return a 200 for all files in the /api/ folder.

**Desired result:**

The API folder can be accessed without the .htpasswd configuration (authentication). The rest of the project requires a .htpasswd. The API folder itself may not be accessed by any external IP. I believe this is the solution for my problem.

**Code**

I am using DirectAdmin to customize the NGINX configuration. This is my full (customized) NGINX config:

```
location ~ ^/api/ {
    auth_basic "off";
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location / {
    auth_basic $authentication;
    auth_basic_user_file /home/admin/domains/test.testsite.com/.htpasswd;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

geo $authentication {
    default "Authentication required";
    127.0.0.1/8 "off";
    ::1/128 "off";
    my.home.ip "off";
}
```

Comment: Try `location /api/` and add `try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;` to the block.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your assistance. Unfortunately it's downloading the PHP file

Comment: Do you have a working PHP configuration?

Comment: Move "location ~ ^/api/" over the "location /" so it gets matched first. And add required extensionless  rewrite inside "location ~ ^/api/".

Comment: @Yarimadam I have updated my question with the new code. Unfortunately it's still only downloading the file rather than executing it. - @Richard Smith; without the API location, the code is being executed just fine (except when you try to retrieve the data with ``file_get_contents``)

Comment: oh, you are not passing php files to php interpreter. thats why it downloads file instead of parsing it. please refer fastcgi_pass.

Comment: @Yarimadam I wasn't aware there was no fallback on the default .php location block, especially since I added the rewrite rule to this location block. Thank you, the problem has been solved.